# How to verify whether a path is windows reserved keyword in Java?

Tags: java, windows

I'm currently working on converting the Go's filepath library to its Java equivalent. However, I've encountered an issue regarding the verification of whether a path is a Windows reserved word. In Go, the following code snippet is used for this purpose:

```golang
    if p, _ := syscall.FullPath(name); len(p) >= 4 && p[:4] == `\\.\` {
        return true
    }
```

To replicate this behavior in Java, I attempted to use the Paths.get method to obtain the path and then check if it starts with \.. However, this resulted in an exception being thrown:

```java
        Path nul = Paths.get("NUL");
        System.out.println(nul.toAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println("NUL is reserved path? " + nul.startsWith("\\\\.\\"));
```

```
java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: UNC path is missing sharename: \\.\

    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:132)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:92)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:231)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Path.startsWith(Path.java:380)
```

I consulted Copilot and attempted to use PowerShell's Test-Path -IsValid "NUL", which returned True.

It appears that neither Java nor PowerShell can accurately identify Windows reserved words. Are there any alternative methods available?

Comment: I can see why Powershell might say that. The 'path' in say `type foo.txt >NUL` would mean that `NUL` is a valid path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\\\\.\\` isn't a valid path by itself. Your test fails because you are using `Path.startsWith(String)` which calls `Path.startsWith(Path)`, and so you must supply a parameter that is a valid `Path`.

You can avoid path check failure by dealing with `String` versions of the path and use `String.startsWith(String)` instead.

This is one area where `File` and `Path` behave differently and I don't think you can use `Path` for this check. Instead use `File.getCanonicalPath` which performs the translation to a long path, and returns `String` which is in the format that you are expecting:

```
File f = new File("NUL");                 // new File(name)
System.out.println(f);                    // ==> prints: NUL
System.out.println(f.getCanonicalPath()); // ==> prints: \\.\NUL

boolean startsSlashSlashDotSlash = f.getCanonicalPath().startsWith("\\\\.\\");
// ==> true
```

Note: You can't rely on your test as it would incorrectly other long paths as "Windows reserved word" - for example this form of C drive `\\\\.\\c:\\` or a Windows UNC share passes your test:

```
File f = new File("\\\\.\\HOST\\SHARE");  // new File(name)
System.out.println(f);                    // ==> \\.\HOST\SHARE
System.out.println(f.getCanonicalPath()); // ==> \\.\HOST\SHARE

boolean startsSlashSlashDotSlash = f.getCanonicalPath().startsWith("\\\\.\\");
// ==> true
```

See also [File path formats on Windows systems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/file-path-formats#dos-device-paths)

Comment: I concur. [getCanonicalPath](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html#getCanonicalPath()) will achieve what you want.